# bullet point in text of plist

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsstring, plist

I have a plist file which contains huge text. In middle of text I have to add bullet points. Is there any way to add bullets in the text like unicode character 2022 and plist will be used in iPad application ?

I googled for this but not found any solution. 
Requesting to please provide me answer for this immediately.

Comment: My answer is not what you are asking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mac you can write - **bullets = ALT + ***

Comment: Thanks ALT * I can use in Mac. Similarly any way in windows machine ? Because my plists are modified at Windows 7 PC.

Comment: I dont know that even i dont know is this possible in window pc or not.... Why dont you use copy and paste method while you're entering it manually ????

Comment: And if this is answer of your question the why're you not accepting it and even you didn't give any vote ???

Comment: When I run the app, copy & paste method is giving slightly bigger size than regular bullet points and that looks ugly. Don't know what is the reason for that.